# Compilation error in ethereum wallet

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to compile the example contract in https://ethereum.org/token and following along with the instructions.

The Ethereum wallet cannot compile it though. I get the following error message

```
 Expected ',' but got identifier
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, 
uint256 _value, address _token, bytes calldata _extraData) external; }

^--------^
```

First time trying to do a contract in Ethereum, and figured that the example code from the official Ethereum website should work. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `solidity` version. If using `solc@0.4.x` then use

```
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, 
uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }
```

Instead of

```
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, 
uint256 _value, address _token, bytes calldata _extraData) external; }
```

Or change the solidity version to `solc@0.5.0`

Comment: How do I change solidity version of Ethereum wallet?

Comment: just remove the `calldata` and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Check your solidity compiler version.
The "calldata" is available **0.5.0 or higher**

Comment: How do I change solidity version of Ethereum wallet?